# How do i use a variable to substr a string and convert it to numeric type in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

i want to add a variable in SSIS to substr 2 string then i will concate them and the result will be converted a numeric type

Comment: What code have you tried? Have you added the variable? What are you having problems with? Any error messages?

Comment: Be more precise with your question and try to formulate it properly, please. This is not google.

Comment: Your question is not clear.   What part of this are you stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Expression Builder that is available for the variables to build the expression you are intending to.